# Case statement syntax when using IN

Tags: sql

```
select distinct 
    i.legacydatetime,
    i.legacypatientreceivablespatientid,
    bs.invoiceid,
    billingserviceid,
    case 
       when billingserviceid not in (select billingserviceid 
                                     from model.billingservices 
                                     where id not in (select billingserviceid 
                                                      from model.adjustments 
                                                      where billingserviceid is not null)) 
         then bs.unit * bs.unitcharge  
         else  bs.unit * bs.unitcharge + total_amount 
     end as Open_Balance
```

I have 2 tables  `model.billingservices` and `model.adjustments` where id of `billingservices` table is the foreign key in `adjustments` table as `billingserviceid`.

I want to segregate those id from billingservices table that are not present in adjustments table and so for that I need to apply some condition, else if the ids are there in adjustments table then need to apply some other condition

Comment: You miss the select keyword at the begining. What is the error message you get

Comment: If you aren't going to post the whole query at least post the error message that you get

Comment: see what i want is : i am taking case and in that if suppose there are 2 tables named billingservices and adjustments, and billingserviceid is a foreign key in adjustments table alright! so now if billingserviceids which are in billingservice table are not present in adjustments then there  should be some condition for those billingserviceids, pl suggest now

Comment: And am not getting any error msg, but either am not getting the desired output!

Comment: I'm suprised because it doesn't look like that would run. Anyway, please edit your question and explaint the output your are getting and the output that you want.

Comment: Done, go through it.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Also, specify the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

```
billingserviceid not in (select * from model.billingservices....
```

Here you are comparing billingserviceid with multiple columns of model.billingservices table by using *. Mention a single column name which you intend to compare against billingserviceid instead. * would return all column values.

Comment: yep i corrected , still am not getting the required output.

Comment: You can't use `select *` in a sub-select for the `IN` operator, you *have* to select only a single column in the sub-select. This will result in an error (unless billingservices has exactly one column)

Comment: select distinct   i.legacydatetime,i.legacypatientreceivablespatientid,bs.invoiceid,billingserviceid, 
case when billingserviceid not in 
(select billingserviceid from model.billingservices a 
left join model.adjustments  b
 on a.billingserviceid=b.billingserviceid where b.billingserviceid IS Null)
 then bs.unit * bs.unitcharge else
 bs.unit * bs.unitcharge+total_amount end as Open_Balance

Comment: I am not sure if above query will help. But try it out.